# PWA, how to pinch and zoom in content of site on iOS?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, pinch

On iOS, I have added my website to Home Screen. After that, i run the website by shortcut, i cannot pinch and zoom in content of site. However, i can do that if run the website via Safari.

I have added those but still not work.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=5.0"> in <head></head>
```

I tried to access to 2 those sites https://app.starbucks.com and https://www.bmw.com. After that, add them to Home Screen and open by shortcut => I can pinch and zoom in content of site.

I want my website can do the same as 2 those sites.

Is there any solution, document or sample code that can help me solve this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your website is a PWA? Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure that my website is a PWA, running with an HTTPS. I can add it to Home Screen. Problem is i can pinch and zoom in on Safari browser but cannot do that when running from shortcut.

Comment: I think need to add some code to do that, but i don't know what should i do.
It works on Android now (both browser and shortcut), and work on Safari browser. Just not work when running from shortcut on iOS

Comment: Adding to the home screen does NOT mean it is a PWA. You can add a shortcut to your home screen for any website. You need to run the chrome Lighthouse tool to let you know if you have all the pieces for a valid PWA.

Comment: Video on the Lighthouse tool. The look of the report has changed since this video was made but still does the same. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVhJtr4_gK8

Comment: Thanks for your helps, it works now although i don't have any updates for code. Weird.
Many thanks.